# background issue in html and css sections

Tags: html, css

The problem I am having with my website is that I am trying to make different sections of background colors on one page. I was able to get the main background color, but then I want a portion of the rest of the site to be another, and the footer to also be a different color. Here is the html code and css that I tried. I couldn't for the life of me figure out what I was doing wrong so if you know what I'm doing wrong that would help a ton! thanks!

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Travel</title>


</head>
<body bgcolor="#045889">
<table>
<tr>
<th><font color="white"><strong>Share Your Travels</strong>
</font> </header></th>
</table>
<table>
<td> <font color="white">Let Us Know Where You've Been</font></td>
</table>
<section>
<h2>Description</h2>
<p>

<i>Photo by Randy Connolly</i>
</p>
<p>

This photo of Conservatory Pond in 
<a href="images_Travel/central_park.jpg">Central Park</a> in 

<a href="images_Travel/related-large3.jpg">New York City</a>
was taken on      October 22, 2014 with a Cannon EOS 30D camera.

</p>
<p><img src="images_Travel/large-central-park.jpg" alt="Travel"/></p>

<p><i>Conservatory Pond in Central Park</i></p>
<p>
Share: <img src="images_Travel/social/email_16.png" alt="Travel"/>
<img src="images_Travel/social/rss_16.png" alt="Travel"/>
<img src="images_Travel/social/twitter_16.png" alt="Travel"/>
<img src="images_Travel/social/facebook_16.png" alt="Travel"/>
<img src="images_Travel/social/flickr_16.png" alt="Travel"/>
</p>
</section>
<h2>Related Photos</h2>
<p>
<img src="images_Travel/related-square1.jpg"alt="Travel"/>
<img src="images_Travel/related-square2.jpg"alt="Travel"/>
<img   src="images_Travel/related-square3.jpg"alt="Travel"/>
</p>
<h2>Reviews</h2>
<p>
<i>by Ricardo on September 25th, 2015 </i> 
</p>
<p>Easy on the HDR Buddy</p>
<p><i>by Susan on October 1, 2015</i>
</p>
<p>I Love Central Park.</p>
<footer>

Copyright &copy; 
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #045889; 
}

table{
font color= ''white'';
text-wrap: normal;
}
```

Comment: You may want to look through your code a bit more carefully first: the font tag is deprecated, and you have a closing header tag, with no opening header tag. Also, tables really aren't a good way to handle layout.  Finally: can you let us know what you want this to look like exactly?  It sounds like you just need to apply background color directly to the elements (like footer).  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: It looks like you also have some malformed css code. "font color= ''white''; should be "color:white"

Comment: I just fixed the header issue in my document. I'm trying to accomplish my webpage to have a blue background for the entire page, the header having the same color background as the footer, and the 'content' so to speak having a white background. Does that make sense? I'm new to html and coding so I apologize if you see me making some silly mistakes.

Comment: @MaKayla don't forget to accept an answer! (Click the checkmark next to the answer that best solves your problem, if any of them did)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parts where you want a different color, try adding a style

```
<footer style="background-color:green">
    Copyright &copy; 
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first off we need to clean up your HTML:

- Tables are a Really Bad thing to use for formatting (almost always).  Instead, it's best to use other html elements as appropriate. However, if you are going to use them make sure to put the `<th>` first (that's your Table Header), then `<tr>` (that's your Table Rows), then put `<td>` (your Table Data) inside of those as cells.
- But a better solution than `<table>` is a `<header>` with `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags in it.  Cleaner to style.
- You need to double check that all of your opening tags have closing tags, and vice versa (see the `</header>` tag in your original code)
- The font tag really isn't used anymore. Your CSS for the table shows that you can format that text color in a better way - we just have to get it to work!
- I've also enclosed the rest of your content in another `<section>` tag so we can target that with CSS separate from the body.
- Formatting your code can seem a bit of a waste of time, especially when you're just working on something for yourself, but it's REALLY helpful when you have a problem you can't sort out.  Generally, you indent 1 tab/a few spaces each time you go a level deeper (nested) into the  HTML.  This makes it super easy to see when you've missed closing a tag.

```
<header>
    <h1>Share Your Travels</h1>
    <h2>Let Us Know Where You've Been</h2>
</header>
<section>
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <p>
        <i>Photo by Randy Connolly</i>
    </p>
    <p>
        This photo of Conservatory Pond in <a href="images_Travel/central_park.jpg">Central Park</a> in <a href="images_Travel/related-large3.jpg">New York City</a> was taken on October 22, 2014 with a Cannon EOS 30D camera.
    </p>
    <p>
        <img src="images_Travel/large-central-park.jpg" alt="Travel"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <i>Conservatory Pond in Central Park</i>
    </p>
    <p>
        Share: <img src="images_Travel/social/email_16.png" alt="Travel"/>
        <img src="images_Travel/social/rss_16.png" alt="Travel"/>
        <img src="images_Travel/social/twitter_16.png" alt="Travel"/>
        <img src="images_Travel/social/facebook_16.png" alt="Travel"/>
        <img src="images_Travel/social/flickr_16.png" alt="Travel"/>
    </p>
</section>
<section>
    <h2>Related Photos</h2>
    <p>
        <img src="images_Travel/related-square1.jpg"alt="Travel"/>
        <img src="images_Travel/related-square2.jpg"alt="Travel"/>
        <img src="images_Travel/related-square3.jpg"alt="Travel"/>
    </p>
    <h2>Reviews</h2>
    <p>
        <i>by Ricardo on September 25th, 2015 </i> 
    </p>
    <p>Easy on the HDR Buddy</p>
    <p>
        <i>by Susan on October 1, 2015</i>
    </p>
    <p>I Love Central Park.</p>
</section>
<footer>
Copyright &copy; 
</footer>
```

For the CSS, there are a couple of fixes and some new styles

- `font color = ''white'';` isn't proper CSS. It should be `color: white;` as is mentioned in the comments already.
- To get the background color to change on elements, you just need to assign classes or ids to those elements, then style them appropriately (`background-color: red;` for example will do it).
- That * is a wildcard: it applies the following styles to everything on the page. Needed to get rid of some default margins on the HTML elements

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #045889; 
}

header {
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    text-wrap: normal;
}

section {
    background-color: yellow;
}

footer {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several errors, and you may want to have a look through it first. Here is a good tool to help you with that: [**W3C Markup Validator**](https://validator.w3.org/) and [**CSS Validator**](http://www.css-validator.org/)

To change the background color of an element, simply use: `background-color:` followed by the color you want.

So for example, to change your `footer` to red, and your `section` to green, you can do:

```
footer {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

section {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

You can also use classes or ids' to mark sections of your page that you want to style. [**W3Schools - CSS Selectors**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)